# Spring IDE installation error 1

Tags: java, spring

when i am installing spring IDE from spring-tool-suite-3.0.0.RELEASE-e4.2-win32-installer.exe
there is a problem,it says jre5 is required to install it, but i am using window Xp and jre6 is already installed on my system.Then what cai i do to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying the location of the jre folder in Eclipse.ini:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.100.v20110502
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vm
C:\Java\JDK\1.6\bin\javaw.exe
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Xms40m
-Xmx1024m
```

http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini